# How to validate view controls against data in the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new at WPF, and I'm getting my head around validators, it seems that you need to inherit from ValidationRule and override the Validate function, this totally separated from the view model,  but what if I want to validate against some list/collection/set/dictionary in the viewmodel, to check whether this new input is not already in the list, a good example would be creating a validation to see whether or not an username is not already taken.

Comment: You might have two kinds of validation to worry about... some things (like a valid email address) are great for client-side validation, but other things (like whether an username is taken) are more suited for server-side validation (because you don't really know if the user can take it until you create that user in your persistent storage). Just a thought.

Comment: And which is the way to implement this kind of server validators in mvvm + wpf or there is no official one?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do Validation in WPF. There's two main ways I can think of off the top of my head

1. Create Validation Rules then apply them in XAML
2. Implement IDataErrorInfo in your ViewModel

Validation Rules are specified in your XAML (GUI), while implementing IDataErrorInfo moves the Validation logic into your ViewModel (Business logic). While, ValidationRules are nice because you can create your own and reuse them, they also fail to provide validation in your business logic which is most likely required.

The concept of Client vs. Server side validation is interesting, perhaps as it pertains to Silverlight, but since you tagged this as WPF, I'm assuming the only difference is whether the validation occurs in the Views or ViewModels (UI or Business logic). It seem to me that even if your UI validated inputs, your ViewModels would still need to do proper validation.

Therefore, I suggest implementing IDataErrorInfo. By the way, the reason IDataErrorInfo works, is because a ValidationRule exists that checks for the IDataErrorInfo Interface! Here's an example of how I would do it in my ViewModelBase class:

**Note:** the immediately following examples ignore the fact you will likely need INotifyPropertyChanged notifications to update your bindings and instead focuses simply on Validation.

```
public class ViewModelBase : IDataErrorInfo
{

    private Dictionary<string, string> errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    // required for IDataErrorInfo
    public virtual string Error
    {
        get { return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors); }
    }

    // required for IDataErrorInfo
    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result;
            errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // Useful property to check if you have errors
    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return errors.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    protected void SetError<T>(string propertyName, String error)
    {
        if (error == null)
            errors.Remove(propertyName);
        else
            errors[propertyName] = error;

        OnHasErrorsChanged();
    }

    protected string GetError<T>(string propertyName, String error)
    {
        String s;
        errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out s);
        return s;
    }

    protected virtual void OnHasErrorsChanged()
    {

    }
}
```

Then your ViewModels can implement it like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return someProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if(someProperty != null)
            {
                someProperty = value;
                SetError("SomeProperty", ValidateSomeProperty());
            }
        }
    }

    private string ValidateSomeProperty()
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeProperty))
            return "Value is required";
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your UI, you'll need to add ValidatesOnDataErrors and NotifyOnValidationError like this:

```
Text="{Binding SomeProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
```

---

**Note:** Passing in strings to represent properties is kinda ugly (it's not refactor safe if you rename the property but forget to rename the string). INotifyPropertyChanged is the same way when you want to notify of property changes for DataBindings. Prism's NotificationObject has a refactor safe solution to this and it looks like this instead:

Replace GetError / SetError in the previous example with this:

```
    protected void SetError<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop, String error)
    {
        String propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(prop);

        if (error == null)
            errors.Remove(propertyName);
        else
            errors[propertyName] = error;

        OnHasErrorsChanged();
    }

    protected string GetError<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop, String error)
    {
        String propertyName = PropertySupport.ExtractPropertyName(prop);

        String s;
        errors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out s);
        return s;
    }
```

And then my ViewModelBase is something like this:

```
public class ViewModelBase : NotificationObject, IDataErrorInfo
```

Then to implement properties:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string someProperty;

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return someProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if(someProperty != null)
            {
                someProperty = value;
                SetError( () => SomeProperty, ValidateSomeProperty()); // update validation for property
                RaisePropertyChanged( () => SomeProperty); // notify data bindings
            }
        }
    }
```

I didn't show the implementation for RaisePropertyChanged but it is in Prism's NotificationObject which is open source and a free download. You can instead implement INotifyPropertyChanged yourself and either raise the event with strings (not refactor safe) or implement it yourself similar to the above implemention for SetError (extract the property name and fire the event with it).

You'll need this helper method:

```
public static class PropertySupport
{
    public static string ExtractPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpresssion)
    {
        if (propertyExpresssion == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");
        }

        var memberExpression = propertyExpresssion.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The expression is not a member access expression.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The member access expression does not access a property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);
        if (getMethod.IsStatic)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The referenced property is a static property.", "propertyExpression");
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit: Simplified Refactor Safe Alternative**

If you are using .NET 4.5 or later, you can use the [CallerMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like [this example shows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for INotifyPropertyChanged and my SetError implementation. Then you wouldn't need to extract the property name yourself via reflection as above (It simplifies it quite a bit).

Sorry to get off track talking about Property Change Notifications, but they go hand in hand if you want your DataBindings and Validation to work!

Answer (score -1):

I Finally did it, this is how :

Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>     
    <l:DataResource x:Key="ValidateFieldMethod" BindingTarget="{Binding IsFieldValid}"/>
</Window.Resources>
            <xctk:IntegerUpDown Width="50" Maximum="300" Minimum="0">
                <xctk:IntegerUpDown.Value>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedItem.TargetPosition" Mode="TwoWay">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <l:CustomValidationRule Validator="{l:DataResourceBinding DataResource={StaticResource ValidateFieldMethod}}"  />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </xctk:IntegerUpDown.Value>
            </xctk:IntegerUpDown>
```

The ValidatorRule:

```
public delegate bool CheckAgainstDataDelegate(object newValue, string fieldName);

public class CustomValidationRule : ValidationRule
{

    public CheckAgainstDataDelegate Validator { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingGroup owner)
    {
        return Validate((object)owner, cultureInfo);
    }
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingExpressionBase owner)
    {
        switch (ValidationStep)
        {
            case ValidationStep.UpdatedValue:
            case ValidationStep.CommittedValue:
                value = (object)owner;
                break;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(Validator(value, ((BindingExpression) owner).ResolvedSourcePropertyName), null);
    }

    [Obsolete("Use Validator property of type delegate instead to validate the data",true)]
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) { return null; } //not used anymore
}
```

In the viewModel :

```
    private CheckAgainstDataDelegate _isFieldValid;
    public CheckAgainstDataDelegate IsFieldValid
    {
        get
        {
            return _isFieldValid
                ?? (_isFieldValid = delegate (object newValue,string propertyName)
                {
                    switch (propertyName)
                    {
                        case "TargetPosition":
                            var newV = (int) newValue;
                            return Items.All(e => e.TargetPosition != newV);
                        default:
                            throw  new Exception("Property Assigned to unknown field");
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

I used the help of http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-add-binding-to-property-on.html to Bind in the ValidationrRule.

What do you Think?

Comment: I think it is needlessly complex, IDataErrorInfo already provides a method of doing this that is simpler. What do you think of my answer?